# testing the cancellation of a simple observable doesn't call onError

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

Given the following:

Why is the `OnError` handler in `Subscribe` never called?

```
var observable = Observable.Create<string>(
    async (o, c) =>
    {
        try
        {
            var strings = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };

            foreach (var s in strings)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                if (c.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // exception thrown here.
                    Console.WriteLine("cancelled");
                    throw new OperationCancelledException();
                }
                o.OnNext(s);
            }
            o.OnCompleted();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // caught here...
            o.OnError(ex);
        }
    });

var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
var token = new CancellationTokenSource();
observable.Subscribe(
    str =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        token.Cancel(); // cancel after the first iteration.
    },
    (e) =>
    {
        // why is this never called.
        Console.WriteLine($"on error :: {e.Message}");
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    },
    () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("on complete");
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    },
    token.Token);

// code hangs here because the subscription never completes?
await tcs.Task;
Console.WriteLine("done");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the base implementation of the observer `OnError` (as well as other functions) contains:

```
if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.isStopped, 1) == 0)
{
    this.OnErrorCore(error);
}
```

The value `isStopped` is set to "stopped" when the token cancels. The observer takes care of the cancellation process and it is not required to control it manually.

You can easily check it if you change your `OnNext` code to

```
if(str == "B")
    token.Cancel(); // cancel after the second iteration.
```

The result will be:

[image]

Even if you remove the `if` statement. No inherited functions will be called after you cancel the token

```
var observable = Observable.Create<string>(
    async (o, c) =>
        {
            var strings = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };

            foreach (var s in strings)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                o.OnNext(s);
            }
            o.OnCompleted();
        });
```

So bearing that in mind, When the token is cancelled (logically it's not an error) don't move the logic to any of the event implementation instead execute the required cancellation logic in the caller code:

```
if (c.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    // exception thrown here.
    Console.WriteLine("cancelled");
    tcs.SetResult(true); // instead of throwing exceptions
    // some other clean up code or/and return statement
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying and I will leave the question open for a little longer - but it seems broken. There should be a deterministic way of dealing with failure.

Comment: I suppose, in documentation should be a sentence like "After a cancellation of the token no events will be executed", I'll try to find it

Comment: Sure - but there should be some way for the subscriber to know it was cancelled? To catch the cancellation exception. It appears not - which to me seems broken

Comment: Ahh now I've got what you meant. The tool that is used (system.reactive) works as I've described, but the user still have access to the cancellation token and have control on the functionality. I'll try to update the answer to solve the exact problem

Answer (score 5):

When you call `Cancel` on the token, you (the subscriber, who passed the token and therefore "own" cancellation) are basically saying "I am no longer interested in events, including OnError()".

Under the covers, Rx inserts an `AutoDetachObserver` in between the observable and the observer which explicitly swallows all further events.

This behaviour is by design.

`OnError()` is there to tell you about failures while you are subscribed. After cancelling the token (which unsubscribes the observer), you aren't subscribed any more and receive no more events. In other words, cancelling a subscription is not an error. And cancelling the token in the observable is not an error or a valid means of communicating one - calling `OnError()` is.

Answer (score 3):

Building off of what James wrote: There's two parts to an Rx subscription, the observable (publisher), and the observer (subscriber). When you *subscribe* to the observable with a cancellation token, you're effectively telling the *subscriber* to cancel the subscription.

In your scenario, this means that as soon as you cancel, the subscriber stops listening. So the `onError` notification won't be listened to, therefore the `Task` never completes.

If you remove the `token` being passed to the subscription call, then the `onError` will flow to the subscription as you expect.

Comment: how would I then pass my cancellation token into the observable implementation?
I need to pass the token into the observable, otherwise the observable has a different token that doesn't respond to my cancel request.
Basically all I want is a token to cancel the observable when I want to?
I am not understanding the pattern - that's clear.

Comment: Good point. Rx pre-dates TPL and cancellation tokens so the integration is a bit shoe-horned. Mixing TPL and Rx often leads to problems like this.